# Netconsole not sending UDP messages

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd

I have set up netconsole logging on a CentOS 7 client. I added

```
SYSLOGADDR=192.168.1.54
SYSLOGPORT=514
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/netconsole`, the ran `systemctl start netconsole.service` and `systemctl enable netconsole.service` on the CentOS client.

On a Debian 10.5 system connected to the same Ethernet switch with IPv4 address `192.168.1.54`, I modified `/etc/rsyslog.conf` by uncommenting the lines

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")
```

then ran `systemctl restart rsyslog` on the server (Debian 10.5). Now when I generate some messages in the `kern.log` on the client (CentOS 7) e.g. by running `modprobe floppy`, the client logs the corresponding messages in its own `kern.log` but generates no UDP messages addressed to the server - as confirmed by tcpdump running on the server as well as another computer attached to the same Ethernet switch. The netconsole service on the client says it started successfully and is running. There are no firewalls either on the server or the client or anywhere in between and tcpdump detects pings sent from the client to the server fine.

Any idea what else to look for?

Comment: can you restart (rather than start) the netconsole service?

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I just tried it, there is no change (i.e. the problem remains as before).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is, that you aren't *sending* anything. the module `imudp` is responsible for *receiving* data.

So with these lines:

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")
```

You're basically saying "**receive** udp messages on port 514".

---

To **forward** the log data, you can use `omfwd`, e.g:

```
action(type="omfwd" target="192.168.1.54" port="514" protocol="udp")
```